# Material UI TextField multiline, make a new line only when pressed Shift Enter

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a chat system built in React and I am using Material UI textfield for submitting a message. I want it to function like whatsapp or telegram on the web version. On enter send the message but on shift enter, make a new line. I have this

```
             <TextField
                autoFocus={true}
                color={"primary"}
                multiline
                rowsMax={4}
                value={inputValue}
                fullWidth
                placeholder={"Please enter a message"}
                onChange={e => {
                  setInputValue(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
```

What should I add to acheive that functionality, is it easy?

Answer (score 3):

Add `onKeyDown` prop to your `TextField`

```
onKeyDown={(e) => {
  if(e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInputValue("");
  }
}}
```

Comment: onKeyDown is not a TextField property !

Comment: @Jean-PierreSchnyder You can also send props to underlying `input` html element. This prop is for that element which you get to pass to `TextField` component.

Answer (score 0):

On a keyDown prop you can do it like this...

```
onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (isMultiline) {
          if ((e.key === 'Enter' && e.altKey) || (e.key === 'Enter' && e.shiftKey)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const textarea = e.target;
            const currentCursorPosition = textarea.selectionStart;
            const textBeforeCursorPosition = textarea.value.substring(0, currentCursorPosition);
            const textAfterCursorPosition = textarea.value.substring(currentCursorPosition);
            const newText = `${textBeforeCursorPosition}\n${textAfterCursorPosition}`;
            textarea.value = newText;
            textarea.setSelectionRange(currentCursorPosition + 1, currentCursorPosition + 1);
            textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
          } else if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault();
            handleSubmit(e);
          }
        }
      }}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).